# How to test javascript function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

Is it possible to test existance of js function in page using Capybara? if so, can I make a call and check result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capybara is used to test the overall functionality of your web application by actually rendering the page. When you are using an engine that can execute Javascript (the default Rack::Test engine does not), you can use it to check that your page is indeed rendered correctly after executing the relevant Javascript. There are ways to test a function's existence by calling `page.execute_script("typeof yourFunctionName == 'function'")` (and only select engines support this) and check its value but know that Capybara it is not designed to be a Javascript test framework. You should use Jasmine for that.

Comment: but how to test js funxtions on different actions of different controllers? is it like visit in capybsra?

Comment: Capybara has no concept of controllers or actions at all. It's just a tool that can visit web pages and renders them. (And if it can execute javascript as well, if it's supported). Think of Capybara like your browser, your browser doesn't care about controllers/actions in the Rails backend, it just knows the HTTP request, and the HTTP response and renders a web page based on the response.

Comment: Can I use Jasmine on action level? how to use it for specific controller and action?

Comment: Jasmine is a front-end Javascript framework. Javascript is not tied to a specific controller or action either because it doesn't know about the Rails backend. The only thing Rails know about Javascript is the view it renders, that will contain Javascript. If you are using Rails 3.1+ with asset pipeline however, Javascript that's put in the assets/javascript folder will **always** be there on **every** page by default.

Comment: I put js functions when I need them, thus they are not always rendered as I check action and controller before I render them, but Jasmine tests will suppose that js functions always there, so it will result in failing tests .. what do you think?